# Scm-manager Export/Backup

Tags: scmmanager

I installed scm-manager on CentOS-7 and import repositories via web browser (previous exported with svnadmin dump).

How can I export/backup repositories via commandline?  Can't find `svn`/`svnadmin` command.

Answer (score 0):

SCM-Manager does not install the subversion binaries, because it uses the java implementation of subversion (svnkit). If you want to use svnadmin to dump the repositories, you have to install subversion by your self e.g.:

```sh
yum install subversion
```

After the installation you can use svnadmin to dump your repositories.